# 画像読み込み時の Permission denied に関して

Tags: python, windows, twitter

python初心者です。
画像tweetしようと以下.pyを作成しました。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

CK = '# Consumer Key' # Consumer Key
CS = '# Consumer Secret' # Consumer Secret
AT = '# Access Token' # Access Token
AS = '# Accesss Token' # Accesss Token Secert

# 画像とテキストのURL
url_media = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json"
url_text = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

# 認証
twitter = OAuth1Session(CK, CS, AT, AS)

# 画像投稿
path = "# 画像ファイルのパス" # 画像ファイルのパス
files = {"media" : open(path, 'rb')}
req_media = twitter.post(url_media, files = files)

# レスポンスを確認
if req_media.status_code != 200:
 print ("Upload image is Failed: %s", req_media.text)
exit()

# IDを取得
media_id = json.loads(req_media.text)['media_id']
print ("Media ID: %d" % media_id)

# IDを付加してテキストを投稿
params = {'status': '#splatoon2 #NintendoSwitch', "media_ids": [media_id]}
req_media = twitter.post(url_text, params = params)

# レスポンスを確認
if req_media.status_code != 200:
 print ("Upload text is Failed: %s", req_text.text)
exit()

print ("OK")
```

上記を実行すると以下のエラーが表示されます。
Cドライブ-デスクトップ配下に画像フォルダがあり、読み取り専用も解除しているのですが、どうしたらよいか分からず。
ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagetweet.py", line 21, in <module>
    files = {"media" : open(path, 'rb')}
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '# 画像ファイルのパス'
```

Comment: 作成したpyスクリプトと同じフォルダに画像を保存して実行するとどうなりますか？ / また、画像が保存してあるデスクトップまでのパス (ユーザー名等) に日本語は含まれていたりしますか？

Answer (score 1):

Pythonを実行するユーザーに適切なアクセス許可が与えられていないのではないでしょうか？

画像ファイルを右クリックし、「プロパティ」を選択して、「セキュリティ」タブをクリックすると、その画像ファイルへのアクセス許可の状態が確認できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事解決いたしました。

Comment: @on1ta217 やはりアクセス許可の問題だったんですか？